# How to define an XML element containing forward slash (/) in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an element in my Soap request as below.

```
<Destination>abc/xyz</Destination>
```

It is failing XML Schema validation. How can I define it in XSD?

I have defined as below and it seems to be not correct:

```
<xs:element name="Destination" type="Destination" minOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:simpleType name="Destination">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <!-- <xs:pattern value="*/*"/> -->
      <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Some typo perhaps? Why would you expect an element named "directory" to be validated against an element declaration named "Destination"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.*/.*` for zero or more characters before and after a `/`:

```
<xs:element name="Destination">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value=".*/.*"/>
      <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: @Michael Kay Yes it was typo. I meant Destination.

Comment: @Michael Kay yes I meant to comment on question. Yes it did help.